# Zonal stats of multiple rasters in Python

Tags: python, zonal-statistics

I have a python script to get the zonal stats for one raster. Trying to use the same for multiple rasters. 
I have seen so many answers on similar post but somehow none seems to be working on mine.

Here is my code for the single raster stats.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.plot import show
from rasterio.mask import mask
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shapely

band1 = rio.open("C:/Users/mahanp/Desktop/BRZ-tmin/tmin/rep/f072_rep.tif.tif")
districts = gpd.read_file("C:/Users/mahanp/Desktop/BRZ-tmin/tmin/rep/test.shp")
#districts = districts[["id", "Name",]]
districts.head()


band1.height
band1.width

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(12, 10))
show(band1, ax=ax)
plt.show()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 10))
show(band1, ax=ax)
districts.plot(ax=ax, color="black", alpha=.90)
plt.show()


def derive_stats(geom, data=band1, **mask_kw):
    masked, mask_transform = mask(dataset=data, shapes=(geom,),
                                  crop=True, all_touched=True, filled=True)
    return masked

districts['max'] = districts.geometry.apply(derive_stats).apply(np.max)
districts['min'] = districts.geometry.apply(derive_stats).apply(np.max)
districts.head()
```

Code for multiple raster

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.plot import show
from rasterio.mask import mask
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shapely
import os
import glob


inraster_path = 'C:\\Users\\MahanP\\Desktop\\BRZ-tmin\\tmin\\rep'
districts = gpd.read_file("C:/Users/mahanp/Desktop/BRZ-tmin/tmin/rep/test.shp")
districts.head()

# Make a search criteria to select the raster files
search_criteria = "*.tif"
inraster = os.path.join(inraster_path, search_criteria)
print(inraster)

# glob function can be used to list files from a directory with specific criteria
zonal_fps = glob.glob(inraster)

# Files that were found:
print(zonal_fps)


# Iterate over raster files and add them to source -list in 'read mode'
for fp in zonal_fps:
    band1 = rio.open(fp)
    band1.height
    band1.width

    districts1 = districts
    districts1.head()

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(12, 10))
    show(band1, ax=ax)
    plt.show()

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 10))
    show(band1, ax=ax)
    districts1.plot(ax=ax, color="black", alpha=.90)
    plt.show()

    def derive_stats(geom, data, **mask_kw):
     masked, mask_transform = mask(dataset=data, shapes=(geom,),
                                  crop=True, all_touched=True, filled=True)
     return masked

    districts1['max'] = districts1.geometry.apply(derive_stats, args=(band1, )).apply(np.max)
    districts1.head()
```

The code just plots the vector file on the raster and nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: With the soon coming out QGIS 3.14 it will be very easy to do. You can try the dev version and run the QGIS processing algorithm from cmd shell. This will reduce a lot of overhead of writing complex code. https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/34617

Comment: Thanks for this info, surely will be of great help.But I have other processes which I need to automate and integrate along with the zonal stats so was thinking Python. If you have any solution on the zonal stats for multiple rasters with separate stats for each raster would be of great help.

Comment: No one on this?

Comment: Have you searched the web they are various python implementations of these https://gist.github.com/perrygeo/5667173 or https://www.perrygeo.com/zonal-stats-with-postgis-rasters.html